# Code Comparison in Oracle DB and SVN

Tags: oracle, svn, tortoisesvn

I need a help of Tool or script that I can check If I can compare the Oracle DB files that are committed to SVN or Not?

I need to check the compiled files in Oracle only.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks,
Dhaval.

Comment: What do you mean with "Oracle DB files"?

Comment: Wernfried, our Schema SQL files or ddl files etc.

Comment: So as I have understand you have files on your machine and you want to check if they are on svn right ? so you can `check out` the scripts from svn localy to a folder then compare the 2 folder (there many free tool on the internet or you can develop a your own tool) the one are missing you put them in one folder then search fo there contents

Comment: Never mention "Tool or script"  in SO. It is off-topic and will most likely to be voted to close.

Answer (score 0):

This might be difficult because even your DDL files in svn are most like different to what you would get from database by `DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL()` for example.

For DML scripts (i.e. UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE statements) I don't see any possibility.

However, for PL/SQL code you can select code from view `USER_SOURCE` and compare with your files in svn.